# Read from HBase with PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, hbase

I'm trying to write/read from HBase with pyspark.

**Environment:**

- CDH 5.13
- Hbase 1.2.0
- Spark 2.3 (installed as percel)
- Python 3.6
- PyCharm

I'm using **HBase Spark Connector Project Core » 1.1.1-2.1-s_2.11**

http://repo.hortonworks.com/content/repositories/releases/com/hortonworks/shc-core/1.1.1-2.1-s_2.11/

**My code is:**

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SQLContext
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from datetime import datetime
import json

conf = (SparkConf()
       .setAppName("RW_from_HBase"))

spark = SparkSession.builder \
     .appName(" ") \
     .config(conf=conf) \
     .getOrCreate()

sc = spark.sparkContext
sqlc = SQLContext(sc)

data_source_format = 'org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase'

catalog = json.dumps(
    {
        "table":{"namespace":"spark", "name":"test_table"},
        "rowkey":"id",
        "columns":{
            "id":{"cf":"rowkey", "col":"id", "type":"string"},
            "filename":{"cf":"content", "col":"filename", "type":"string"},
            "created_ts":{"cf":"content", "col":"created_ts", "type":"string"},
            "html":{"cf":"content", "col":"html", "type":"string"}
        }
    })

# Writing into HBase
mydf.write\
    .options(catalog=catalog, newtable = 5)\
    .format(data_source_format)\
    .save()

# Reading from Hbase
df = sqlc.read\
    .options(catalog=catalog)\
    .format(data_source_format)\
    .load()

df.show()
```

**My spark submit is:**

```
--master local[*] --packages com.databricks:spark-avro_2.11:4.0.0,com.hortonworks:shc-core:1.1.1-2.1-s_2.11 --repositories http://repo.hortonworks.com/content/repositories/releases/ --queue PyCharmSpark pyspark-shell
```

When I do write to HBase, everything works fine and data from mydf saved into HBase table.

When I'm trying to read it works fine, only until spark action. 
df.show() - causes an error.

```
WARNING: Running spark-class from user-defined location.
http://repo.hortonworks.com/content/repositories/releases/ added as a remote repository with the name: repo-1
Ivy Default Cache set to: /home/cloudera/.ivy2/cache
The jars for the packages stored in: /home/cloudera/.ivy2/jars
:: loading settings :: url = jar:file:/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2-2.3.0.cloudera2-1.cdh5.13.3.p0.316101/lib/spark2/jars/ivy-2.4.0.jar!/org/apache/ivy/core/settings/ivysettings.xml
com.databricks#spark-avro_2.11 added as a dependency
com.hortonworks#shc-core added as a dependency
:: resolving dependencies :: org.apache.spark#spark-submit-parent;1.0
    confs: [default]
    found com.databricks#spark-avro_2.11;4.0.0 in central
    found org.slf4j#slf4j-api;1.7.5 in central
    found org.apache.avro#avro;1.7.6 in central
    found org.codehaus.jackson#jackson-core-asl;1.9.13 in central
    found org.codehaus.jackson#jackson-mapper-asl;1.9.13 in central
    found com.thoughtworks.paranamer#paranamer;2.3 in central
    found org.xerial.snappy#snappy-java;1.0.5 in central
    found org.apache.commons#commons-compress;1.4.1 in central
    found org.tukaani#xz;1.0 in central
    found com.hortonworks#shc-core;1.1.1-2.1-s_2.11 in repo-1
    found org.apache.hbase#hbase-server;1.1.2 in central
    found org.apache.hbase#hbase-protocol;1.1.2 in central
    found org.apache.hbase#hbase-annotations;1.1.2 in central
    found com.github.stephenc.findbugs#findbugs-annotations;1.3.9-1 in central
    found log4j#log4j;1.2.17 in central
    found junit#junit;4.11 in central
    found org.hamcrest#hamcrest-core;1.3 in central
    found com.google.protobuf#protobuf-java;2.5.0 in central
    found org.apache.hbase#hbase-procedure;1.1.2 in central
    found com.google.guava#guava;12.0.1 in central
    found com.google.code.findbugs#jsr305;1.3.9 in central
    found org.apache.hbase#hbase-client;1.1.2 in central
    found commons-codec#commons-codec;1.9 in central
    found commons-io#commons-io;2.4 in central
    found commons-lang#commons-lang;2.6 in central
    found io.netty#netty-all;4.0.23.Final in central
    found org.apache.zookeeper#zookeeper;3.4.6 in central
    found org.slf4j#slf4j-api;1.7.7 in central
    found org.slf4j#slf4j-log4j12;1.6.1 in central
    found org.apache.htrace#htrace-core;3.1.0-incubating in central
    found org.jruby.jcodings#jcodings;1.0.8 in central
    found org.jruby.joni#joni;2.1.2 in central
    found commons-httpclient#commons-httpclient;3.1 in central
    found commons-collections#commons-collections;3.2.1 in central
    found com.yammer.metrics#metrics-core;2.2.0 in central
    found com.sun.jersey#jersey-core;1.9 in central
    found com.sun.jersey#jersey-server;1.9 in central
    found commons-cli#commons-cli;1.2 in central
    found org.apache.commons#commons-math;2.2 in central
    found org.mortbay.jetty#jetty;6.1.26 in central
    found org.mortbay.jetty#jetty-util;6.1.26 in central
    found org.mortbay.jetty#jetty-sslengine;6.1.26 in central
    found org.mortbay.jetty#jsp-2.1;6.1.14 in central
    found org.mortbay.jetty#jsp-api-2.1;6.1.14 in central
    found org.mortbay.jetty#servlet-api-2.5;6.1.14 in central
    found org.codehaus.jackson#jackson-jaxrs;1.9.13 in central
    found tomcat#jasper-compiler;5.5.23 in central
    found org.jamon#jamon-runtime;2.3.1 in central
    found com.lmax#disruptor;3.3.0 in central
    found org.apache.hbase#hbase-prefix-tree;1.1.2 in central
    found org.mortbay.jetty#servlet-api;2.5-20081211 in central
    found tomcat#jasper-runtime;5.5.23 in central
    found commons-el#commons-el;1.0 in central
    found org.apache.hbase#hbase-common;1.1.2 in central
    found org.apache.phoenix#phoenix-core;4.9.0-HBase-1.1 in central
    found org.apache.tephra#tephra-api;0.9.0-incubating in central
    found org.apache.tephra#tephra-hbase-compat-1.1;0.9.0-incubating in central
    found org.apache.tephra#tephra-core;0.9.0-incubating in central
    found com.google.code.gson#gson;2.2.4 in central
    found com.google.guava#guava;13.0.1 in central
    found com.google.inject#guice;3.0 in central
    found javax.inject#javax.inject;1 in central
    found aopalliance#aopalliance;1.0 in central
    found org.sonatype.sisu.inject#cglib;2.2.1-v20090111 in central
    found asm#asm;3.1 in central
    found com.google.inject.extensions#guice-assistedinject;3.0 in central
    found ch.qos.logback#logback-classic;1.0.9 in central
    found ch.qos.logback#logback-core;1.0.9 in central
    found org.apache.thrift#libthrift;0.9.0 in central
    found org.apache.httpcomponents#httpcore;4.1.3 in central
    found it.unimi.dsi#fastutil;6.5.6 in central
    found org.apache.twill#twill-common;0.6.0-incubating in central
    found com.google.code.findbugs#jsr305;2.0.1 in central
    found org.apache.twill#twill-core;0.6.0-incubating in central
    found org.apache.twill#twill-api;0.6.0-incubating in central
    found org.apache.twill#twill-discovery-api;0.6.0-incubating in central
    found org.apache.twill#twill-zookeeper;0.6.0-incubating in central
    found org.apache.twill#twill-discovery-core;0.6.0-incubating in central
    found org.ow2.asm#asm-all;5.0.2 in central
    found io.dropwizard.metrics#metrics-core;3.1.0 in central
    found org.antlr#antlr-runtime;3.5.2 in central
    found jline#jline;2.11 in central
    found sqlline#sqlline;1.2.0 in central
    found joda-time#joda-time;1.6 in central
    found com.github.stephenc.jcip#jcip-annotations;1.0-1 in central
    found junit#junit;4.12 in central
    found org.apache.httpcomponents#httpclient;4.0.1 in central
    found commons-logging#commons-logging;1.2 in central
    found org.iq80.snappy#snappy;0.3 in central
    found commons-collections#commons-collections;3.2.2 in central
    found org.apache.commons#commons-csv;1.0 in central
    found org.apache.hbase#hbase-annotations;1.1.3 in central
    found org.apache.hbase#hbase-protocol;1.1.3 in central
    found org.apache.hadoop#hadoop-common;2.7.1 in central
    found org.apache.hadoop#hadoop-annotations;2.7.1 in central
    found org.apache.commons#commons-math3;3.1.1 in central
    found xmlenc#xmlenc;0.52 in central
    found commons-net#commons-net;3.1 in central
    found javax.servlet#servlet-api;2.5 in central
    found com.sun.jersey#jersey-json;1.9 in central
    found org.codehaus.jettison#jettison;1.1 in central
    found com.sun.xml.bind#jaxb-impl;2.2.3-1 in central
    found javax.xml.bind#jaxb-api;2.2.2 in central
    found javax.xml.stream#stax-api;1.0-2 in central
    found javax.activation#activation;1.1 in central
    found org.codehaus.jackson#jackson-xc;1.9.2 in central
    found net.java.dev.jets3t#jets3t;0.9.0 in central
    found org.apache.httpcomponents#httpcore;4.2.5 in central
    found com.jamesmurty.utils#java-xmlbuilder;0.4 in central
    found commons-configuration#commons-configuration;1.6 in central
    found commons-digester#commons-digester;1.8 in central
    found commons-beanutils#commons-beanutils;1.7.0 in central
    found commons-beanutils#commons-beanutils-core;1.8.0 in central
    found org.apache.hadoop#hadoop-auth;2.7.1 in central
    found org.apache.directory.server#apacheds-kerberos-codec;2.0.0-M15 in central
    found org.apache.directory.server#apacheds-i18n;2.0.0-M15 in central
    found org.apache.directory.api#api-asn1-api;1.0.0-M20 in central
    found org.apache.directory.api#api-util;1.0.0-M20 in central
    found org.apache.curator#curator-framework;2.7.1 in central
    found org.apache.curator#curator-client;2.7.1 in central
    found com.jcraft#jsch;0.1.42 in central
    found org.apache.curator#curator-recipes;2.7.1 in central
    found org.apache.hadoop#hadoop-mapreduce-client-core;2.7.1 in central
    found org.apache.hadoop#hadoop-yarn-common;2.7.1 in central
    found org.apache.hadoop#hadoop-yarn-api;2.7.1 in central
    found com.sun.jersey#jersey-client;1.9 in central
    found com.google.inject.extensions#guice-servlet;3.0 in central
    found com.sun.jersey.contribs#jersey-guice;1.9 in central
    found org.slf4j#slf4j-log4j12;1.7.10 in central
    found io.netty#netty;3.6.2.Final in central
    found javax.servlet.jsp#jsp-api;2.1 in central
:: resolution report :: resolve 27998ms :: artifacts dl 2975ms
    :: modules in use:
    aopalliance#aopalliance;1.0 from central in [default]
    asm#asm;3.1 from central in [default]
    ch.qos.logback#logback-classic;1.0.9 from central in [default]
    ch.qos.logback#logback-core;1.0.9 from central in [default]
    com.databricks#spark-avro_2.11;4.0.0 from central in [default]
    com.github.stephenc.findbugs#findbugs-annotations;1.3.9-1 from central in [default]
    com.github.stephenc.jcip#jcip-annotations;1.0-1 from central in [default]
    com.google.code.findbugs#jsr305;2.0.1 from central in [default]
    com.google.code.gson#gson;2.2.4 from central in [default]
    com.google.guava#guava;13.0.1 from central in [default]
    com.google.inject#guice;3.0 from central in [default]
    com.google.inject.extensions#guice-assistedinject;3.0 from central in [default]
    com.google.inject.extensions#guice-servlet;3.0 from central in [default]
    com.google.protobuf#protobuf-java;2.5.0 from central in [default]
    com.hortonworks#shc-core;1.1.1-2.1-s_2.11 from repo-1 in [default]
    com.jamesmurty.utils#java-xmlbuilder;0.4 from central in [default]
    com.jcraft#jsch;0.1.42 from central in [default]
    com.lmax#disruptor;3.3.0 from central in [default]
    com.sun.jersey#jersey-client;1.9 from central in [default]
    com.sun.jersey#jersey-core;1.9 from central in [default]
    com.sun.jersey#jersey-json;1.9 from central in [default]
    com.sun.jersey#jersey-server;1.9 from central in [default]
    com.sun.jersey.contribs#jersey-guice;1.9 from central in [default]
    com.sun.xml.bind#jaxb-impl;2.2.3-1 from central in [default]
    com.thoughtworks.paranamer#paranamer;2.3 from central in [default]
    com.yammer.metrics#metrics-core;2.2.0 from central in [default]
    commons-beanutils#commons-beanutils;1.7.0 from central in [default]
    commons-beanutils#commons-beanutils-core;1.8.0 from central in [default]
    commons-cli#commons-cli;1.2 from central in [default]
    commons-codec#commons-codec;1.9 from central in [default]
    commons-collections#commons-collections;3.2.2 from central in [default]
    commons-configuration#commons-configuration;1.6 from central in [default]
    commons-digester#commons-digester;1.8 from central in [default]
    commons-el#commons-el;1.0 from central in [default]
    commons-httpclient#commons-httpclient;3.1 from central in [default]
    commons-io#commons-io;2.4 from central in [default]
    commons-lang#commons-lang;2.6 from central in [default]
    commons-logging#commons-logging;1.2 from central in [default]
    commons-net#commons-net;3.1 from central in [default]
    io.dropwizard.metrics#metrics-core;3.1.0 from central in [default]
    io.netty#netty;3.6.2.Final from central in [default]
    io.netty#netty-all;4.0.23.Final from central in [default]
    it.unimi.dsi#fastutil;6.5.6 from central in [default]
    javax.activation#activation;1.1 from central in [default]
    javax.inject#javax.inject;1 from central in [default]
    javax.servlet#servlet-api;2.5 from central in [default]
    javax.servlet.jsp#jsp-api;2.1 from central in [default]
    javax.xml.bind#jaxb-api;2.2.2 from central in [default]
    javax.xml.stream#stax-api;1.0-2 from central in [default]
    jline#jline;2.11 from central in [default]
    joda-time#joda-time;1.6 from central in [default]
    junit#junit;4.12 from central in [default]
    log4j#log4j;1.2.17 from central in [default]
    net.java.dev.jets3t#jets3t;0.9.0 from central in [default]
    org.antlr#antlr-runtime;3.5.2 from central in [default]
    org.apache.avro#avro;1.7.6 from central in [default]
    org.apache.commons#commons-compress;1.4.1 from central in [default]
    org.apache.commons#commons-csv;1.0 from central in [default]
    org.apache.commons#commons-math;2.2 from central in [default]
    org.apache.commons#commons-math3;3.1.1 from central in [default]
    org.apache.curator#curator-client;2.7.1 from central in [default]
    org.apache.curator#curator-framework;2.7.1 from central in [default]
    org.apache.curator#curator-recipes;2.7.1 from central in [default]
    org.apache.directory.api#api-asn1-api;1.0.0-M20 from central in [default]
    org.apache.directory.api#api-util;1.0.0-M20 from central in [default]
    org.apache.directory.server#apacheds-i18n;2.0.0-M15 from central in [default]
    org.apache.directory.server#apacheds-kerberos-codec;2.0.0-M15 from central in [default]
    org.apache.hadoop#hadoop-annotations;2.7.1 from central in [default]
    org.apache.hadoop#hadoop-auth;2.7.1 from central in [default]
    org.apache.hadoop#hadoop-common;2.7.1 from central in [default]
    org.apache.hadoop#hadoop-mapreduce-client-core;2.7.1 from central in [default]
    org.apache.hadoop#hadoop-yarn-api;2.7.1 from central in [default]
    org.apache.hadoop#hadoop-yarn-common;2.7.1 from central in [default]
    org.apache.hbase#hbase-annotations;1.1.3 from central in [default]
    org.apache.hbase#hbase-client;1.1.2 from central in [default]
    org.apache.hbase#hbase-common;1.1.2 from central in [default]
    org.apache.hbase#hbase-prefix-tree;1.1.2 from central in [default]
    org.apache.hbase#hbase-procedure;1.1.2 from central in [default]
    org.apache.hbase#hbase-protocol;1.1.3 from central in [default]
    org.apache.hbase#hbase-server;1.1.2 from central in [default]
    org.apache.htrace#htrace-core;3.1.0-incubating from central in [default]
    org.apache.httpcomponents#httpclient;4.0.1 from central in [default]
    org.apache.httpcomponents#httpcore;4.2.5 from central in [default]
    org.apache.phoenix#phoenix-core;4.9.0-HBase-1.1 from central in [default]
    org.apache.tephra#tephra-api;0.9.0-incubating from central in [default]
    org.apache.tephra#tephra-core;0.9.0-incubating from central in [default]
    org.apache.tephra#tephra-hbase-compat-1.1;0.9.0-incubating from central in [default]
    org.apache.thrift#libthrift;0.9.0 from central in [default]
    org.apache.twill#twill-api;0.6.0-incubating from central in [default]
    org.apache.twill#twill-common;0.6.0-incubating from central in [default]
    org.apache.twill#twill-core;0.6.0-incubating from central in [default]
    org.apache.twill#twill-discovery-api;0.6.0-incubating from central in [default]
    org.apache.twill#twill-discovery-core;0.6.0-incubating from central in [default]
    org.apache.twill#twill-zookeeper;0.6.0-incubating from central in [default]
    org.apache.zookeeper#zookeeper;3.4.6 from central in [default]
    org.codehaus.jackson#jackson-core-asl;1.9.13 from central in [default]
    org.codehaus.jackson#jackson-jaxrs;1.9.13 from central in [default]
    org.codehaus.jackson#jackson-mapper-asl;1.9.13 from central in [default]
    org.codehaus.jackson#jackson-xc;1.9.2 from central in [default]
    org.codehaus.jettison#jettison;1.1 from central in [default]
    org.hamcrest#hamcrest-core;1.3 from central in [default]
    org.iq80.snappy#snappy;0.3 from central in [default]
    org.jamon#jamon-runtime;2.3.1 from central in [default]
    org.jruby.jcodings#jcodings;1.0.8 from central in [default]
    org.jruby.joni#joni;2.1.2 from central in [default]
    org.mortbay.jetty#jetty;6.1.26 from central in [default]
    org.mortbay.jetty#jetty-sslengine;6.1.26 from central in [default]
    org.mortbay.jetty#jetty-util;6.1.26 from central in [default]
    org.mortbay.jetty#jsp-2.1;6.1.14 from central in [default]
    org.mortbay.jetty#jsp-api-2.1;6.1.14 from central in [default]
    org.mortbay.jetty#servlet-api;2.5-20081211 from central in [default]
    org.mortbay.jetty#servlet-api-2.5;6.1.14 from central in [default]
    org.ow2.asm#asm-all;5.0.2 from central in [default]
    org.slf4j#slf4j-api;1.7.7 from central in [default]
    org.slf4j#slf4j-log4j12;1.7.10 from central in [default]
    org.sonatype.sisu.inject#cglib;2.2.1-v20090111 from central in [default]
    org.tukaani#xz;1.0 from central in [default]
    org.xerial.snappy#snappy-java;1.0.5 from central in [default]
    sqlline#sqlline;1.2.0 from central in [default]
    tomcat#jasper-compiler;5.5.23 from central in [default]
    tomcat#jasper-runtime;5.5.23 from central in [default]
    xmlenc#xmlenc;0.52 from central in [default]
    :: evicted modules:
    org.slf4j#slf4j-api;1.7.5 by [org.slf4j#slf4j-api;1.7.7] in [default]
    org.slf4j#slf4j-api;1.6.4 by [org.slf4j#slf4j-api;1.7.7] in [default]
    org.apache.hbase#hbase-protocol;1.1.2 by [org.apache.hbase#hbase-protocol;1.1.3] in [default]
    org.apache.hbase#hbase-annotations;1.1.2 by [org.apache.hbase#hbase-annotations;1.1.3] in [default]
    junit#junit;4.11 by [junit#junit;4.12] in [default]
    com.google.guava#guava;12.0.1 by [com.google.guava#guava;13.0.1] in [default]
    com.google.code.findbugs#jsr305;1.3.9 by [com.google.code.findbugs#jsr305;2.0.1] in [default]
    org.slf4j#slf4j-log4j12;1.6.1 by [org.slf4j#slf4j-log4j12;1.7.10] in [default]
    commons-collections#commons-collections;3.2.1 by [commons-collections#commons-collections;3.2.2] in [default]
    commons-lang#commons-lang;2.5 by [commons-lang#commons-lang;2.6] in [default]
    org.apache.httpcomponents#httpclient;4.1.3 by [org.apache.httpcomponents#httpclient;4.0.1] in [default]
    org.apache.httpcomponents#httpcore;4.1.3 by [org.apache.httpcomponents#httpcore;4.2.5] in [default]
    org.apache.zookeeper#zookeeper;3.4.5 by [org.apache.zookeeper#zookeeper;3.4.6] in [default]
    org.codehaus.jackson#jackson-core-asl;1.9.2 by [org.codehaus.jackson#jackson-core-asl;1.9.13] in [default]
    org.codehaus.jackson#jackson-mapper-asl;1.9.2 by [org.codehaus.jackson#jackson-mapper-asl;1.9.13] in [default]
    org.apache.httpcomponents#httpcore;4.0.1 by [org.apache.httpcomponents#httpcore;4.2.5] in [default]
    commons-codec#commons-codec;1.7 by [commons-codec#commons-codec;1.9] in [default]
    org.codehaus.jackson#jackson-jaxrs;1.9.2 by [org.codehaus.jackson#jackson-jaxrs;1.9.13] in [default]
    org.apache.httpcomponents#httpclient;4.2.5 by [org.apache.httpcomponents#httpclient;4.0.1] in [default]
    org.apache.avro#avro;1.7.4 by [org.apache.avro#avro;1.7.6] in [default]
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    |                  |            modules            ||   artifacts   |
    |       conf       | number| search|dwnlded|evicted|| number|dwnlded|
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    |      default     |  142  |   9   |   9   |   20  ||  122  |   0   |
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
:: retrieving :: org.apache.spark#spark-submit-parent
    confs: [default]
    0 artifacts copied, 122 already retrieved (0kB/387ms)
18/07/12 03:02:08 WARN util.Utils: Your hostname, quickstart.cloudera resolves to a loopback address: 127.0.0.1; using 192.168.116.128 instead (on interface eth1)
18/07/12 03:02:08 WARN util.Utils: Set SPARK_LOCAL_IP if you need to bind to another address
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
[Stage 0:>                                                          (0 + 1) / 1]18/07/12 03:04:37 ERROR executor.Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Scan.setCaching(I)Lorg/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Scan;
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase.HBaseTableScanRDD.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$hbase$HBaseTableScanRDD$$buildScan(HBaseTableScan.scala:223)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase.HBaseTableScanRDD$$anonfun$8.apply(HBaseTableScan.scala:280)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase.HBaseTableScanRDD$$anonfun$8.apply(HBaseTableScan.scala:279)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:186)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.map(ArrayOps.scala:186)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase.HBaseTableScanRDD.compute(HBaseTableScan.scala:279)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

As far as I see the problem is - that Hortonworks build shc-core with HBase 1.1.2 version dependency, but I use Hbase 1.2.0. It might be that there is no some classes or so in jars, loaded for hbase 1.1.2 from central Maven repo. Pls correct me, not sure the root cause of this error.

I've found the explanation of this error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Scan.setCaching(I)Lorg/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Scan
```

here:
https://github.com/hortonworks-spark/shc/issues/154

Can I resolve it not building source code localy? And some people replied that rebuilding didn't resolve this issue. Or is there any other aproach reading from HBase with PySpark?

Pls advise why there is a problem with reading from HBase. And how I can avoid it?

Answer (score 0):

This problem can often be caused by the fact that the installed version is not the same as the version used in the project, or the differences in dependency sources. Please check the version of the hbase in your project.